# Create a categorical randomized vector w/ ordinal constraints in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I'm looking to create a data frame which is essentially a composite of randomized vectors. The idea is that each vector represents some elements of a user path (represented by letters), and the data frame is an aggregation of all those paths.

I've created the data frame the following way (there's likely a more efficient approach)

```
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(25, sample(LETTERS[1:10])))
paths <- data.frame(t(df1[-1]))
colnames(paths) <- rownames(df1)

> head(paths)
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
X2 A B D F E J I H C  G
X3 F E A I H G D C J  B
X4 H I A J B G E F C  D
X5 B J E I A D C G F  H
X6 F D C J A G B E I  H
X7 H I J B D A C E F  G
```

But I want to add some conditions of probability. For example, in any given row sequence of letters, "A" should come any time before "C" with 70% probability, "B" AND "D" should come any time before "F" with 40% probability, "D" should *always* come immediately before "G" -- that sort of thing. Users cannot loop back into a given sequence (though I'd also be interested to know how to represent that, as well -- separate question)

I know that it is possible to add probability constraints when generating random sequences of numbers, but here I need to specify an ordinal structure with probability constraints for categorical variables. Have to admit, I'm not even sure where to start.

Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you say "A should come before C with 70% probability", do you mean A should be immediately before C or any time before C? Does each path have the same probability of being first? And it looks like users cannot return to previous paths, correct?

Comment: Great add -- adjusting the main question to reflect